# How to get the file modification date in UTC from Python

Tags: python

I want to get the modification date of a file in UTC from Python. The following code returns dates in my Linux configured time zone (GMT-5). I want it in UTC. Or how do I get the os configured time zone to convert it with pytz ?

```
$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import os
>>> dt=os.path.getmtime('/home/user/.bashrc')
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dt)
datetime(2012, 5, 30, 21, 18, 10)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try [datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp)

```
import datetime
import os
dt=os.path.getmtime('/home/me/.bashrc')
print (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dt))
print (datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(dt))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your local timezone in place of "America/New_York" and the following should do the trick.

```
In [11]: import datetime, pytz

In [12]: right_now = datetime.datetime.now()

In [13]: right_now_utc = right_now.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone("America/New_York")).astimezone(pytz.utc)

In [14]: right_now
Out[14]: datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 9, 20, 31, 21, 999536)

In [15]: right_now_utc
Out[15]: datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 10, 1, 31, 21, 999536, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```